# Is google maps marker always set in midway of the street if we do not provide building number?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-maps-markers

I am not sure and couldn't find the answer if it's true:
if I provide address in form [City],[Street] without providing building number will the marker be placed in the midway of the street's length?

Comment: If that street is in the Geocoder's database, I believe that is the result you will get (but not always, and not guaranteed)

Comment: can i obtain throught google's maps api the maximum street number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right ladies and gentelmen!

EXAMPLE:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Mogilska,Krak%C3%B3w&sensor=true

You got in JSON the lattitiude and longitiude for BOTH ENDS of the street:

```
 "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 50.0706315,
                  "lng" : 19.9826629
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 50.065573,
                  "lng" : 19.9586112
               }
            },
```

NORTHEAST is point S on the map,SOUTHWEST is point E on the map:

TO THE POINT OF QUESTION, you can easily calculate the mid of the way coordinates, like this:

[image]

But it will be OK IF AND ONLY IF it is perfect STRAIGHT line. In MOST CASES it will lead rather to STRANGE results.(like X on the map).

THANKFULY Google result some aproximate mid point of street calculated in this fragment (point M on map):

```
"location" : {
               "lat" : 50.0666145,
               "lng" : 19.9706876
            },
```

[image]

Comment: That is the _bounds_ of the street.  In this case it may work (the road runs from the southWest corner of the bounds to the northEast corner of the bounds, but won't work if the road is not that way.

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you very much for good point. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Which basically boils down to my comment on the initial question.